# Inexact objects in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I used to using Flow for typing. How do type an inexact object?

I have this array:

```
const arr = [
        {label: 'Set', value: setNumber, id: 'setNumber', set: setSetNumber, type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Name', value: name, id: 'name', set: setName, type: 'text'},
        {label: 'Source', value: source, id: 'source', set: setSource, type: 'text'}
    ]
```

It inferes the type well except that I want 'type' to be:

```
type InputType = 'text' | 'number'
```

How do I type this one property without cancelling out the inferencing of all the other properties?

Comment: Cast to `'text' | 'number'`

Comment: Please [edit] the code here to be a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates what you're seeing if I paste it into my own IDE.  Right now there are undeclared values that are distracting from your question and make it hard for others to make a suggestion we can test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `as const` to each of the relevant strings, eg:

```
[
        {label: 'Set', value: setNumber, id: 'setNumber', set: setSetNumber, type: 'text' as const},
        {label: 'Name', value: name, id: 'name', set: setName, type: 'text' as const},
        {label: 'Source', value: source, id: 'source', set: setSource, type: 'text' as const}
    ]
```

This tells ts that this is a literal, not just a string

Answer (score 0):

you can use a second variable with it's type inferred from the previous one where you cast the item's 'type' property:

```
var list = [
    { label: 'Set', value: setNumber, id: 'setNumber', set: setSetNumber, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Name', value: name, id: 'name', set: setName, type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Source', value: source, id: 'source', set: setSource, type: 'text' }
];

var list2 = list as Array<typeof list[number] & { type: 'text' | 'number' }>;
```